# blankpage while trying phpmyadmin

Tags: xampp, localhost

I have installed xampp in my windows.  when I try to start apache and mysql it is getting started but while running in browser I m getting apache running successfully but phpmyadmin is executing but it is showing a blank page without any error! what's the solution

Comment: Any hints in the webserver error log?

Comment: no there were no hints at all...jus a blank page but in xampp control panel I can make mysql start .....something is wrong !! couldn't find